# Error in Bell series of arithmetic functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

I want to prove that $$\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = \sum_{d|n} \frac{\mu(d)^2}{\varphi(d)}.$$ First clear denominators to get $$n = \sum_{d|n} \mu(d)^2 \varphi(n/d).$$ Next I replaced $\mu(d)^2$ with $\lambda^{-1}(d)$ and rewrote as $$i * \lambda = \varphi$$ the computed then Bell series of both sides to get $$\frac{1}{1 - px} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + x} = \frac{1 - x}{1 - px}.$$ This is not an equality so I think I have a mistake somewhere?

- $\lambda$ is the Liouville function with Bell series $\frac{1}{1 + x}$.
- $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function with Bell series $\frac{1 - x}{1 - px}$.
- $i$ is the identity function with Bell series $\frac{1}{1 - px}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error: In general, $\varphi(n)/\varphi(d) \not= \varphi(n/d)$.

Comment: What about in the case that $d|n$?

Comment: I see, even if $d|n$ it doesn't mean that $(d,n/d) = 1$. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I did not mean to say that you made another error, I just wanted to make clear that I did not check the rest of your argument.

Comment: @user9325, it was confusing how you said "in general" since I had the condition $d|n$ but I see why my argument was wrong now. Thanks. BTW Why don't you have a name? You can be anonymous on this site but you don't have to have a random number as your identifier.

Comment: @user9325, how is this username generated?

Comment: @user9325, it's okay I found out that the name is generated by openid or whatever web software is used to register.